# How to call function with PaintEventArgs argumnt?

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code example from MSDN:

```
private void GetPixel_Example(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\tanyalebershtein\Desktop\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg");

        // Get the color of a pixel within myBitmap.
        Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(50, 50);

        // Fill a rectangle with pixelColor.
        SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(pixelColor);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
```

How can one call the `Paint` function?

Comment: Maybe you should post MSDN link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the paint event something like this

```
private PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
   GetPixel_Example(e) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call this method from a PaintEvent of a form e.g.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }

    //....

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GetPixel_Example(e);
    }

    private void GetPixel_Example(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\tanyalebershtein\Desktop\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg");

        // Get the color of a pixel within myBitmap.
        Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(50, 50);

        // Fill a rectangle with pixelColor.
        SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(pixelColor);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

1. Loads the image
2. Get the color of the pixel at x=50,y=50
3. Draw a filled rectangle with that color at 0,0 with a size of 100,100
   on the [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)-Object of the form

Answer (score 0):

You should't call the `Paint` method yourself. The `Paint` method will be called by the .NET framework whenever your component needs to be painted. This typically happens when the window is moved, minimized, etc.

If you want to tell the .NET framework to repaint your component, call `Refresh()` on either the component or one of its parents.