# Painting from a separate thread?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, graphics

I'm currently working on a game that uses the graphics class to create all the pic's in the game, i'm also trying to paint the pic's from a separate thread to stop my main thread from freezing. But every time i try to run the program, the form appears with nothing on it and i get this error...

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> > at Single_Player.Form1.mainPaint(PaintEventArgs e) in c:\users\samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Single_Player\Single_Player\Form1.vb:line 12

If my code did work i was expecting it to move an ellipse across the screen, anyway here's my code...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim paintT As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf mainPaint)
    paintT.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub mainPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    Dim playerX As Integer = 0
    Dim playerY As Integer = 206
    Do While 0 / 0
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black)), 0, 0, 884, 24)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black)), 0, 0, 884, 24)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Life: 5", New Font("DigifaceWide", 20, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, Color.Green)), 2, 0)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Score: 0", New Font("DigifaceWide", 20, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, Color.White)), 100, 0)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Blue)), playerX, playerY, 24, 24)
        playerX = playerX + 1
        playerY = playerY + 1
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Update (again)**
My code so far (this time i've added a timer via the design window)...

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Timer1.Interval = 50
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub mainBackgroundPB_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black)), 0, 0, 884, 24)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black)), 0, 0, 884, 24)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Life: 5", New Font("DigifaceWide", 20, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, Color.Green)), 2, 0)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Score: 0", New Font("DigifaceWide", 20, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, Color.White)), 100, 0)
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Blue)), playerX, playerY, 24, 24)
    playerX = playerX + 1
    playerY = playerY + 1
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's because `PaintEventArgs` is null, you haven't pass it to `mainPaint` from caller thread

Comment: also why do you want to paint on a differeent thread, just use a timer if you want something to occur repeadidly as you cannot paint from another thread.

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk: so how would i pass the arguments to mainPaint?

Comment: `Do while 0/0` is a strange construct. This is first generating `Double.Infinity` then casting it to boolean. Why not just use while true

Comment: Not sure, just found it easier to type. Well i'll try using timers, not sure how it will work, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: you can pass one argument to the tread using `Thread.Start(Object)` but your then going to run into a whole other set of problems

Comment: @Sam http://stackoverflow.com/a/11753379/1112547 move painting to another method and create new thread with reference to that method in `mainPaint`

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk: Thanks, i'll rearrange my code and see if it works...

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753345/how-to-call-function-with-painteventargs-argumnt/11753379#11753379 has nothing to do with this question, doing it like that will lead to the animation becoming unpredictable as the paint event is called unpredictably or result in the method hanging the ui thread.

Comment: @user1937198: Ok, so how exactly would i implement a timer to produce the animation?

Comment: Handle the `Timer.Tick` event rather the `.paint` event

Comment: That's all? Ok, at first i thought i'd have to start messing around with different arguments. lol. Thanks.

Comment: Ok now, i'm getting an error on line 6, saying "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types".

Comment: Do what it says :)  To use `Handles` on a variable, the variable must be declared as a class-level field using the `WithEvents` keyword, like this: `Private WithEvents _MyTimer As Timer`.  Alternatively, you could just drag a `Timer` component onto your form in the designer.

Comment: Thanks, and yet again another error pop's up (oh, the joys of debugging, lol), this time it's "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs'.", any idea's, i have absolutely no clue how to solve this one...

Comment: Change `e As PaintEventArgs` to `e As EventArgs`.

Comment: Then i get the error "'Graphics' is not a member of System.EventArgs"

Comment: Instead of using `e.Graphics`, create a new graphics object, like this: `Dim g As Graphics = mainBackgroundPB.CreateGraphics()`, then use that to draw.

Comment: Excellent, it finally works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot paint in a worker thread, windows are fundamentally thread-unsafe.  Your timer Tick event handler will crash and burn when the timer ticks.  The Tick event doesn't have a PaintEventArgs argument.

Only the Paint event has those arguments, add that event and move your code.  You can trigger the paint with the timer, make the event handler look like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are incorrect. It *CAN* be done, and then it *CAN* be done even better.

Timers run at a preset interval, which can be good for predictabilitys sake, but bad for performance as it will always run at the same speed or slower. Timers are expensive in games, so use them accordingly, if at all.

Below is a quick example I wrote up showing drawing in a thread, passing it off to a delegate and using a scanning layer to write the image to the main UI.

Suggestions for improvement are commented as well.

```
Public Class Form1

Enum enumGameObjectTypes
    RedBox = 0
    BlueBox = 1
    YellowCircle = 2
End Enum

Structure structGameObjects
    Dim Type As enumGameObjectTypes
    Dim Location As Point
End Structure

' When you have global variables, they are accessible outside the thread.
' You cannot access them on the drawing thread however, without using SyncLock to lock
' the object.
Public GameObjects As New List(Of structGameObjects)
Public tDrawingThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DrawingThread)

' We have to use delegates to pass the image
Delegate Sub DrawingDelegateSub(TheDrawnImage As Image)
Public DrawingDelegate As DrawingDelegateSub

' Set this to true when it's time to exit cleanly
Public _ExitThreadSafelyNow As Boolean = False

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim rand As New Random

    For cnt = 1 To rand.Next(5, 20)
        ' Create some game objects
        Dim newObj As New structGameObjects
        With newObj
            .Type = rand.Next(0, 2)
            .Location = New Point(rand.Next(0, cnt * 100), rand.Next(0, cnt * 50))
        End With
    Next

    ' Set up a delegate (basically a worker that can "move data between threads" safely) 
    DrawingDelegate = AddressOf DrawImage

    ' Start the thread
    tDrawingThread.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub DrawImage(ByVal DrawnImage As Bitmap)

    Dim tmpImage As New Bitmap(1024, 768)

    ' Draw the image to the picture box using an intermediary layer...
    ' The reason we dont just say pb.Image = DrawnImage is because the bitmaps are passed by pointer references NOT just by the image
    ' So, passing it direct would be non-thread safe.
    '
    ' This also isn't the *right* way to do this, but it is just an example.
    '
    ' What we're doing is all the heavy lifting in the thread and then we're scanning pixel by pixel through the image drawn by the thread.
    ' 
    ' The performance here will be awful, so the fix; if you can understand how it works, is to use Bitmap.LockBits;
    ' Performance will ramp up 1000x right away. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx
    For x = 1 To DrawnImage.Width - 1
        For y = 1 To DrawnImage.Height - 1
            tmpImage.SetPixel(x, y, DrawnImage.GetPixel(x, y))
        Next
    Next

    pb.Image = tmpImage
    Debug.Print("Wrote frame !")
End Sub

' Main drawing loop
Sub DrawingThread()
    Dim rectBounds As New Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768)

    '
    '
    Do Until _ExitThreadSafelyNow = True

        ' Set up the next frame
        Dim ImageBuffer As New Bitmap(rectBounds.Width, rectBounds.Height)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ImageBuffer) ' Create the graphics object
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rectBounds)

        ' Lock the gameobjects object until we're done using it.
        SyncLock GameObjects
            For Each obj In GameObjects
                Select Case obj.Type
                    Case enumGameObjectTypes.RedBox
                        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, New Rectangle(obj.Location.X, obj.Location.Y, 15, 15))
                        '
                    Case enumGameObjectTypes.BlueBox
                        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, New Rectangle(obj.Location.X, obj.Location.Y, 20, 20))
                        '
                    Case enumGameObjectTypes.YellowCircle
                        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, New Rectangle(obj.Location.X, obj.Location.Y, 15, 15))
                        '
                    Case Else
                        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Pink, New Rectangle(obj.Location.X, obj.Location.Y, 15, 15))
                End Select
            Next
        End SyncLock


        '/// All done drawing by this point...

        'TODO: Eventually implement Bitmap.LockBits here!


        SyncLock ImageBuffer
            ' Send the image onto the main thread.
            Call DrawingDelegate(ImageBuffer)
        End SyncLock


    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

    _ExitThreadSafelyNow = True
End Sub
End Class
```