# calling a method with arguments in mouse click event

Tags: c#

how can i call a method with system arguments in a mouse click event:

```
public void DrawStringRectangleF(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Create string to draw.
    String drawString = "Sample Text";

    // Create font and brush.
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // Create rectangle for drawing. 
    float x = 150.0F;
    float y = 150.0F;
    float width = 200.0F;
    float height = 50.0F;
    RectangleF drawRect = new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);

    // Draw rectangle to screen.
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, width, height);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawRect);
}
```

i want to call this method in this event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // calling DrawStringRectangleF(PaintEventArgs e) here
        }
```

it's easy to call a method if the parameters are variables just by mentioning the values when calling these methods, but how to call it in such a case?!

Comment: Check in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753345/how-to-call-function-with-painteventargs-argumnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to satisfy the existing method signature you could encapsulate the `Graphics` instance that you wish to use to draw  the rectangle within an instance of the `PaintEventArgs` class like this

```
using (var controlGraphics = CreateGraphics())
{
    var paintEventArgs = new PaintEventArgs(controlGraphics, ClientRectangle);
    DrawStringRectangleF(paintEventArgs);
}
```

The `Control.CreateGraphics` method will produce a `Graphics` instance that you can use to paint on the underlying control (or form).

Understand that everything painted with that `Graphics` object will be erased each time the control is invalidated so you must re-draw the graphic continuously.

You may consider adapting the method signature so that it accepts an instance of `Graphics` instead which should make for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the Paint() event and a List of a custom class to store the information about what should be drawn:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public class TextData
    {
        public string Text;
        public string FontName;
        public int FontSize;
        public RectangleF TextRectF;
        public Color TextColor;
    }

    private List<TextData> Texts = new List<TextData>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);

        TextData td = new TextData();
        td.Text = "Example";
        td.FontName = "Courier";
        td.FontSize = 24;
        td.TextRectF = new RectangleF(50.0F, 50.0F, 175.0F, 75.0F);
        td.TextColor = Color.Red;
        Texts.Add(td);
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextData td in Texts)
        {
            using (Pen drawPen = new Pen(td.TextColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(drawPen, Rectangle.Round(td.TextRectF));
            }
            using (Font drawFont = new Font(td.FontName, td.FontSize))
            {
                using (SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(td.TextColor))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(td.Text, drawFont, drawBrush, td.TextRectF);            
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextData td = new TextData();
        td.Text = "Sample Text";
        td.FontName = "Arial";
        td.FontSize = 16;
        td.TextRectF = new RectangleF(150.0F, 150.0F, 200.0F, 50.0F);
        td.TextColor = Color.Black;
        Texts.Add(td);
        this.Refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: A inherited class should never subscribe to it's own events. You should be overriding [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) instead of subscribing to the `this.Paint` event. (be sure to add a `base.OnPaint(e)` to the start of the function, other than that the handler function requires no changes to switch from event to overlaod)

Comment: Why not @ScottChamberlain?  If I subscribe to the Paint() event using the VS IDE, this is exactly what it does (albeit across two different files).  Why doesn't Microsoft instead insert a method stub that overrides OnPaint()?...

Comment: I understand the whole encapsulation aspect, and that subscribing to the event requires delegates and events to be raised, etc...but in the grand scheme of things does it really matter for an example like this?

Comment: Well it is [the recommended way to be done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx). Also, like you said "subscribing requires deleteges and events to be raised etc..." There is a performance overhead with that. The change is trivial, you just remove the subscription line and change the first lines of the paint method to `protected override OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) { base.OnPaint(); \\Rest of code here}` and that is it. Also with `Paint` you can ensure that your painting happens before or after any other painting has been done depending on where the `base.OnPaint()` call is